# Moving Phonegap Android app to Blackberry

Tags: android, blackberry, compilation, cordova

I have a Phonegap app written for Android and am trying to now compile it to work on Blackberry. I followed the instructions at http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/31930982/Getting%20Started%20with%20PhoneGap%20BlackBerry%20WebWorks using the Eclipse approach. I used ant to create a project, then added the javascript/html/css code for the app to that folder. After I opened Eclipse created a BB WebWorks project and imported the folder with the app in it by importing from filesystem.

The app compiles fine and the cod files show up in the output folder, but then never shows up on the simulator. Anybody have any insight on this? I expected I'd have to iron out quite a few bugs between platforms, but I figured it'd compile and show up.

Comment: are you able to see the app icon. are you sure your using the right emulator version ?